# Dictionary and variables value

Tags: python-3.x

I can't put the value from the variable, in dict.

Here is my code:

```py
a = 'Hello World'
dict = {'Key0':'Im here, {a}', 'Key1':200}
print(dict)
```

I want put the value from 'a' variable inside dict, the value from dict is an string.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use f-strings but missing the `f`. Try `f'Im here, {a}'`

Comment: tks, work here.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the value of `Key0` is `Im here, {a}`, you could achieve this using the [replace()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm) string method provided by Python.

```py
a = 'Hello World'
dict = {'Key0':'Im here, {a}', 'Key1':200}
dict['Key0'] = dict['Key0'].replace('{a}', a)
print(dict)
```

Output:

```py
{'Key0': 'Im here, Hello World', 'Key1': 200}
```